# receiving messages with high frequence, asking for the 'best' thread model

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, boost-asio

We are planning a re-design of a framework modul in our software. This module receives messages from a field bus (CAN-bus). The amount of messages can be up to 3000 per second. A single message is rather small (8 byte plus one or two int).
The requirement of the driver is, that I has to use in minimum one blocking receive-function call per channel. There are two or four channels to support.
The amount of the objects which receive the messages are up to 80. Today every object has its own receiving thread, which has some disadvantages. One message can have more than one receiving object.
The objects will be triggered from timers too and interact with each other.

Every object can run in its own thread, but this is not a requirement. It is possible that all objects run in only one thread.

programming language is C++; the OS is Windows 7. We are using boost.thread yet and planning to use boost.asio. In general our software is running on quad core PCs.

My question is: what is the 'best' thread model to distribute the work on several threads?
Should we directly call the objects in the receiving thread? Should we post the messages in a second thread owned by the receiving object? Should we use thread groups or pools, if Yes how?

Comment: All your "models" are viable. I suggest you set up tests with all of them, and see which ones fit your system best (not only when it comes to throughput, but also how it can be integrated with the rest of your system, and possible other considerations as well).

Comment: good suggestion, but this causes some extra work. I hope on some hits or tipps, or some experiences from other people. What are the things, which I had to look at?

Answer (score 0):

> I hope on some hits or tipps...

### note: this is just a hint.

i had a similar problem to solve and did some testing and measurment. and as Joachim Pileborg mentioned in his comment all models are viable. as you mentioned using boost.asio here are my results:

**async:**
[image]

**sync:**
[image]

the values are respond time delays in milliseconds (extracted about 3000 packets from a list with about 1M), but not neccessary. the important think is, sync seems to be more stable.

it realy depends on how and what you are planing to do (e.g is it time critical, do the packages have to be lossless), but in my case the best choice was receiving synchronous with 1 thread per receiver (6 channels where used, so 6 threads), and sending asynchronous in one thread, since there was not realy something timecritical.

i want to keep the answer quit short, so hope this helps a bit out.

Comment: thanks for this answer. Can You explain what I see exactly on both images please. I suppose the lowermost image show Your 'best choice'.
Are were the threads working, if You produce the upper one?

Comment: sorry if my answer is a bit missleading. the images show you the respond timings using async/non-blocking model (though, there was no big difference between using a pool or not), while the second image used a blocking model. my problem was, the latency in receiving (i had to have lower than 2.5 millisec). but the sending was no problem, since it was not critical (i interpolated/extrapolated the data). so my best choice was a mix. using for each channal a single thread to receive (bonded -> **no pool**), but using one single thread for all channels to send.

Comment: @cpp-progger i would suggest you to do a small test what is better in your case.